# React Native: Allow only a certain screen to change orientation

Tags: react-native, video

I was wondering if it is possible to lock all screens on iOS and Android, except for one screen. I have a video player that I want to show in full screen after rotation, but all other screens need to be the only portrait.

I use react-native-video for this.

I manage to get it rotating when using the samples but I need to set the possible orientations in XCODE and Android studio.

I also tried react-native-orientation and put a .lockToPortrait() on it but after tilting, it changes again.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Add some of the code you have used to try to lock the orientation for the screen

Comment: If anyone searching for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640554/14981336) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been through something similar. I want to lock only one screen to landscape. I've tested both `react-native-orientation` and `react-native-orientation-locker`. Neither of them worked as expected. It locks for the first time, but after going back and forth to the locked landscape screen, it slips to portrait.

However, I managed to register for an `addOrientationListener` to make a double check and force it to always stay in landscape. See code bellow.

```
_onOrientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
  if (orientation == 'PORTRAIT') {
    Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
  Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()
  Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
}
```

Even if it slips to portrait, it goes back to landscape.

Maybe you could create a Superclass with the above behaviour and make every screen extend it, expect for that one.

Comment: Orientation seems to be deprecated. I guess it's not working any more. Any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: @vickykeshri did you get any other option to fix orientation for some screen in react-native ?

Comment: @Punita unfortunately no. I have a feeling it might be possible if you go more native; I mean, If it would be possible to register a native activity and somehow use it on js code.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const {navigation} = props

useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.DEFAULT);
    });

    navigation.addListener("blur", () => {
      ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT);
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

the `focus` event is triggered when the screen which we want to allow screen rotation and the `blur` event is trigerred when the user leaves the screen containing this code and is then restricted to PORTRAIT (in this case.)

Comment: this works with functional components, expo and you can also use `const navigation = useNavigation();`

Comment: if this is a better answer then please accept and upvote this answer.

Comment: @Abhishek ScreenOrientation is from `react-native-orientation` package?

Comment: @AlineMatos It is from expo-screen-orientation.

Comment: This snippet works only with expo or expo bare workflow, despite being a good answer, the fact that op is using react-native-video makes it the wrong answer in that case because nothing indicates that he is using any of the expo packages.

Answer (score 1):

React navigations provide the orientations

```
 <Stack.Screen
            name="SelectionsScreen"
            component={SelectionsScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              orientation: 'portrait',
            }}
          />
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#orientation

Answer (score 0):

Since, the orientation option in the options prop of Stack.Screen did not work. And I'm not using expo ... I implemented a work around. Namely I rotated the content of the screen 90 dec.

```js
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
   <View style={{
    padding: 50,
    transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg'}],
    width:'100%', 
    height: '100%' 
}}>
      {children} 
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```