# react-native-orientation in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, screen-orientation

I have a project in React Native, and I need to lock an orientation with a specific view in landscape orientation. But, the code doesn't work and the screen loop tilting. I found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715043/react-native-allow-only-a-certain-screen-to-change-orientation) for the problem very similar to mine. But, the solution proposed here doesn't work. I already searched very hard for one solution.

Sorry for the bad English. Someone can help me?

[this is a result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPcNQ.gif)

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function _onOrientationDidChange(orientation) {
      if (orientation == 'PORTRAIT') {
        Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
      }
      console.log(orientation);
    }
    Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(_onOrientationDidChange);

    //cleanup optional code
    return () => {
      Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
      Orientation.removeOrientationListener(_onOrientationDidChange);
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you please tell me your project react-native and react-native-orientation-locker version?

Comment: Hi, my version of react-native is **0.61.3** and a version of react-native-orientation-locker is **1.1.6**.

Answer (score 3):

I have created new RN project as per your version configurations. App.js full code here.

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.3",
"react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.1.7"
```

Its working fine. Hope you have linked `react-native-orientation-locker` properly in pod file.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
   function _onOrientationDidChange(orientation) {
    if (orientation == 'PORTRAIT') {
      Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
    }
    console.log(orientation);
  }
    Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(_onOrientationDidChange);

    //cleanup optional code
    return () => {
       Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()
       Orientation.removeOrientationListener(_onOrientationDidChange);
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Asha, I try reproduce your code, but my screen just rotate one time. Curiously, my console log print LANDSCAPE-LEFT when my screen is portrait.

[see the result](https://giphy.com/gifs/W3HgUVE2U5h2ULuraf/fullscreen)

Comment: Hi @Asha, I try your code but dont get the right behavior about the screen. I check the versions of dependencies (same with your project), I check the react-native-orientation-locker in pod file and locks fine. I try run in iPhone 7 simulator (and others) but no result. 
The app just rotate one time. I really dont know whats the problem, I edit my post with full code.
You run the app in emulator of xcode?

Comment: @IgorWilliam I can run your code in simulator. What is the actual behaviour you expected? explain it in detail

Comment: Hi @Asha, I just need one of my app's screen locker in landscape and others screens lock in portrait. This is the reason why I don't  lock all the screens in a orientation in xcode settings. Because i need just one screen in a portrait orientation and others in landscape orientation. If you need more details, you can ask-me. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Open ios project in xcode, then in the project_name.xcodeproj section.

uncheck landscape left and landscape right.

ike the picture above.

Comment: Hi @zidniryi, I can't try this way, because I need just one screen of my app lock in a portrait and others screens lock in landscape. If I try this way, all of screens in my app still in orientation portrait. The code example of my post show the mechanism I try developer to solve this problem. I can provide more details if you want.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. I have Xcode 14, on Iphone 16, w/ React native, only checking portrait and verifying portrait only exists wthin Info.plist still allows for the screen to be rotated

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to [Confuguration](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker#configuration) section in the Library's Readme