# How to unlock rotation on one screen in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, rotation, screen-rotation

I tried using react-native-orientation in a webview to get it being the only view that would rotate.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation"

export function GameWebViewScreen({navigation}) {
const link = ****

useEffect(() => {
    Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
}, [])

return <WebView source={{uri: link}}/>
}
```

I am getting TypeError: null in not an object on unlockAllOrientations call. Does anyone know is this a problem because I haven't configured the native files as it says in instructions [here](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) since I don't have the access to them yet or?

I also tried with class component and got the same result.

I am also open for any other suggestions on libraries for controlling rotation on single views.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for this EXACT question, but for plain React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set native files as per instructions and Try to do [manual linking](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#manual-linking).

Listen to device orientation changes in React Native applications and programmatically set preferred orientation on a per screen basis. Works on both Android and iOS.

**Example:-**

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation'

componentDidMount() {
   Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   Orientation.lockToPortrait();
}
```

You need to set app delegate as follow in **ios**

```
#import "Orientation.h"

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
  return [Orientation getOrientation];
}
```

**Android** need to set **Orientation Package**

Implement onConfigurationChanged method in MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent; // <--- import 
import android.content.res.Configuration; // <--- import 

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
     intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
     this.sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
}
```

You can find more information here [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)

Answer (score 8):

If ready to use **native-stack**

in React Navigation v6 use below import

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Website" 
        component={Website} 
        options={{orientation: 'all'}} 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

in React Navigation v5 use below import

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from 'react-native-screens/native-stack';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Website"
        component={Website} 
        options={{screenOrientation: 'all'}} 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Bro, your solution is better than ChatGPT, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `useEffect` instead of `component...Mount` and I didn't manage to only lock a single screen to landscape and go back to portrait afterwards. I really tried everything like: `addOrientationListener` , `unlockAllOrientations`, configurations in Xcode etc. but it just didn't work.

Out of desperation I finally rotated the whole view like `transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}],`. I know it's not THE answer but at least in my case (interactive videos with selection options) it was an acceptable alternative, especially since the rest of the app is in portrait mode.